# tokens transfered out after swap in

Tags: ethers.js, contract-invocation, bsc, wallet-transfer

I am learning ethers.js and try swap tokens via ethers.js, and my transaction succeed buy my wallet had 0 tokens. Then i checked on bscscan and found that after my 'swap' transaction succeed, the target token constract tranfer the tokens out from my wallet to 0x00 address.

here is my transaction:
https://bscscan.com/tx/0x2de1beddd69a6ce052c1cf4b987d0cc74e2e71702edd2932c717a9497c3be6b5

here is the tranfer to 0x00:
https://bscscan.com/tx/0x5a7764632e13372eebd8e030b1f36bc5cc3d9a30b3162b3c9a86060fc0102014

so how it works and why ,  It's hard for me to understand that why other transactions on this contract didnt trigger the next transfer , can any body help me ?

Answer (score 0):

I found a similar transaction:https://www.reddit.com/r/CryptoCurrency/comments/138eo3a/balance_showing_zero_after_token_swapwas_i_scammed/

It seems like the contract owner had a backdoor to burn anyone's token, and i'm still curious that this "burning" did'nt always happen in every transaction，only some specific addresses were burned. So what's the source cause of it, how doea the owner distinguish the 'lucky' guys ?